# Override DateTime serialization for ASP.NET WebMethod parameters

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am working on cleaning up a bug in a large code base where no one was paying attention to local time vs. UTC time.

What we want is a way of globally ignoring time zone information on DateTime objects sent to and from our ASP.NET web services.  I've got a solution for retrieve operations.  Data is only returned in datasets, and I can look for DateTime columns and set the DateTimeMode to Unspecified.  That solves my problem for all data passed back and forth inside a data set.

However DateTime objects are also often passed directly as parameters to the web methods.  I'd like to strip off any incoming time zone information.  Rather than searching through our client code and using DateTime.SpecifyKind(..) to set all DateTime vars to Undefined, I'd like to do some sort of global ASP.NET override to monitor incoming parameters and strip out the time zone information.

Is such a thing possible?  Or is there another easier way to do what I want to do?

Just to reiterate -- I don't care about time zones, everyone is in the same time zone.  But a couple of users have machines badly configured, wrong time zones, etc.  So when they send in July 1, 2008, I'm getting June 30, 2008 22:00:00 on the server side where it's automatically converting it from their local time to the server's local time.

**Update:** One other possibility would be if it were possible to make a change on the client side .NET code to alter the way DateTime objects with Kind 'Undefined' are serialized.

Answer (score 4):

I have dealt with this often in many applications, services, and on different platforms (.NET, Java, etc.).  Please believe me that you do NOT want the long term consequences of pretending that you don't care about the time zone.  After chasing lots of errors that are enormously difficult and expensive to fix, you will wish you had cared.

So, rather than stripping the time zone, you should either capture the correct time zone or force a specific time zone.  If you reasonably can, get the various data sources fixed to provide a correct time zone.  If they are out of your control, then force them either to the server's local time zone or to UTC.

The general industry convention is to force everything to UTC, and to set all production hardware clocks to UTC (that means servers, network devices like routers, etc.).  Then you should translate to/from the user's local time zone in the UI.

If you fix it correctly now, it can be easy and cheap.  If you intentionally break it further because you think that will be cheaper, then you will have no excuses later when you have to untangle the awful mess.

Note that this is similar to the common issue with Strings:  there is not such thing as plain text (a String devoid of a character encoding) and there is no such thing as a plain (no time zone) time/date.  Pretending otherwise is the source of much pain and heartache, and embarrassing errors.

Comment: No, we want to strip time zone information.  We do not have access to client installations, we cannot change preexisting database data to UTC time due to many different apps accessing data.  If someone selects July 1 from a date select item, we can't have it come to the server as June 30.

Comment: Still this does not require a down-vote. The answer is legitimate in the scope of the question (the question did not specify restrictions).

Comment: -1 this wasn't the answer to his question at all, you are making assumptions about the details of his project.

Comment: @Element & @Clyde: I am just trying to save you some hassle by pointing out YOUR assumptions, based on extensive experience.  Simply put, ignoring time zone WILL come back to bite you:  it is only a question of how soon and how painfully.  You have been warned, and I won't waste any more of my time.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I do have a workaround for this, which depends on the fact that I only actually need the Date portion of the DateTime.  I attach this property to every Date or DateTime parameter in the system

```
<XmlElement(DataType:="date")>
```

This changes the generated wsdl to have the type s:date instead of s:dateTime. (Note that simply having the type of the .NET method parameter be a Date rather than a DateTime did NOT accomplish this).  So the client now only sends the date portion of the DateTime, no time info, no time zone info.

If I ever need to send a Date and Time value to the server, I'll have to use some other workaround, like making it a string parameter.

Comment: Please note that you did not remove the time info, you merely zeroed it, which can skew your data and produce subtle errors.  Nevertheless, it is your risk and it will become your problem.  You asked, we warned.

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues with the time zone information as well.  The problem is I'm already providing the datetime fields in UTC.  Then the serialization occurs and the local offset becomes part of the date/time.  The dates/times for our vendor in a different timezone were pretty messed up.  I got around this problem by using the tsql convert function on the datetime fields in my select statement I used to populate my datasets.  This converted the fields to a string variable, which translates nicely to a datetime value automatically on the client side.  If you just want to pass the date, you can use the 101 code to provide just the date.  I used 126 to provide the date and time exactly how it appears in my database columns, with the timezone information stripped out.