# DateTime received from an ASP.NET response is off by a few hours

Tags: asp.net, api, get

An ASP.NET Core API answers a HTTP GET with an object that contains the following DateTime object. As you can see it is guaranteed to be Midnight 12:00:00 in the object before it goes on the wire.

```
e.Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10); 
Debug.Assert(e.Date.TimeOfDay.Equals(TimeSpan.Zero));
```

The web client checks the response as follows.

```
...some context omitted...

DateTime d0 = w.Expiries.First().Date;
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10);
Console.WriteLine(d0.ToString("yyyy MMM dd hh:mm:ss"));
Console.WriteLine(d1.ToString("yyyy MMM dd hh:mm:ss"));
Debug.Assert(d0.Equals(d1));;
```

The output is…

```
2020 Jul 31 08:00:00 // this was not expected
2020 Aug 01 12:00:00 // this was the expected result
```

Of course the client-side assertion will fail.

I am using Microsoft dependencies. At the server:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
Microsoft.NETCore.App
```

At the client:

```
Microsoft.NETCore.App
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (5.2.7)
```

What is the most common solution for this kind of discrepancy?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607727/datetime-time-zone-conversion-in-net-web-service

Comment: The time zone for the client and your server is probably different. For me, usually when working with different time zones, I would convert them to UTC to make comparisons, after that I will convert it back to the respective time zone to display it back to the client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is caused by timezone difference between your server and client. I'd suggest to use UTC when returning date time from your server like `DateTime.UtcNow`. Then in your client, if you want to compare dates, ensure that they are both UTC.

Comment: This is exactly what's happening.

Comment: It turned out this server is located in North America but DateTime.Now equals DateTime.UtcNow despite DateTime.Now.Kind being equal to DateTimeKind.Local.